# Type annotations of undeclared variables

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I've inherited a project that uses a home-made templating system, which works like this:

```
# main code

include_template('page.php', array('user' => $user, 'account' => $account));

# template 'engine'

function include_template($path, $vars) {
    extract($vars);
    include $path;
}
```

and the template "page.php" is an ordinary php/html file, e.g.:

```
 <h1><?= $user->name ?></h1>
 <p>Balance: <?= $account->balance ?></p> etc
```

The variables that are passed to `include_template` are visible in `page.php` because of `extract`, but the IDE (phpstorm) has no clue about them, so it highlights them as undefined and doesn't provide autocompletion etc. Is there a way to annotate an undeclared variable in `page.php` (a "bare" php/html file), so that the IDE can see it?

Comment: If you really want to, you can use $user=$user; which will not do anything, but will tell the IDE that that variable has been declared and given a value.

Comment: I try to implement similar logic in additional phpstom plugin. You can see how it works in this page https://github.com/funivan/ViewablePhpStorm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare it inside page.php. See the following code. It works in PHPStorm.

```
<?php
/**
 * @var User $user
 * @var Account $account
 */
?>
<h1><?= $user->name ?></h1>
<p>Balance: <?= $account->balance ?></p> etc
```